# Minimum number of divisibility tests required in order to identify a number between $1$ and $n$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

There is an unknown number $x (1 \le x \le n)$. You have to guess that number. The only thing you are allowed is that you can ask question.

*Is $x$ divisible by $y$?  $[1 \le y \le n]$*

What will be the minimum number of questions needed in order to guess the number correctly?

e.g. if $n = 4$,

you need to ask at least $3$ questions :

> If $x$ is divisible by $2$?
>
> If $x$ is divisible by $3$?
>
> If $x$ is divisible by $4$?

Hence, if $x$ is not divisible by any number, it is $1$. If its divisible by $4$, $x=4$. If its divisible by $3$, $x=3$, else $x=2$.

Hence, the answer is $3$ questions needed. Can anyone please generalize it for $n$?

IMO, I need to at least test divisibility for all primes $\le n$. What else?

**Example 2**

For $n=6$, answer will be : $4$. You need to ask at least $4$ questions in the worst case to identify any number between $1$ and $6$. Hence, you will ask divisibility for $2,3,4,5$ to identify any number between $1$ and $6$.

Comment: Do you have to have a fixed list, or can you change what questions you want to ask depending on the response? For instance, if the answer to "is it divisible by $2$" is "no", can you skip asking about $4$? And if the answer is "yes", can you skip asking about $3$? That would get it down to two questions.

Comment: @Arthur : You must be able to identify all the numbers between 1 and n. So NO. Its a fixed list. One time you may get 2 in question, next time you may have 4. You have to find minimum set of questions that may identify any number between 1 and n. That means, there will be few questions at times, which you will never ask and still will be able to identify number. e.g if n=7, and you asked *is it divisible by 7?* and luckily x was 7 only, so in just 1 question you identified, but the answer will not be 1. Your set of questions must be able to identify all the numbers between 1 and n.

Comment: But as I said, if I get $2$, then I first ask "is it divisible by $2$"? The answer is "yes", so I _know_ that it cannot also be divisible by $3$. Therefore I don't need to ask that question this time around. Next time I get $1$, so when I ask "is it divisible by $2$" I get the answer "no". Therefore I _know_ that $x$ cannot be divisible by $4$, so I don't have to ask about that. Or is that not allowed?

Comment: In the worst case you'd have to check every prime power between $1$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$.

Comment: @barakmanos Almost. In that case you cannot distinguish between, say, $n$ and $\sqrt n$ if $n$ is the square of a prime, or between $6$ and $18$ if $n \leq 80$.

Comment: @Arthur: Or if $n$ is any other power of a prime.

Comment: @Arthur : At the beginning, you only know n. So you have to keep your set of questions ready without knowing what x can be. Hence, you must be ready for worst case also. Hope, now its clear.

Comment: @Arthur : See one more example in the **EDIT**

Comment: For every prime $p\in[2,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor]$, check the divisibility of $n$ with $p^k$ for every $k$ such that $p^k\in[2,n]$.

Comment: @barakmanos : you mean *x*?

Comment: @InsaneCoder: Yes, I meant "check the divisibility of $x$".